# How can I create an empty hash-map in clojure

Tags: clojure

It gives me a ArrayMap as I code

```
(class (hash-map))
```

But it comes out a HashMap when I code:

```
(class (hash-map "" ""))
```

Question is "How can I create an empty hash-map"?

Comment: Clojure thinks you should keep really small unsorted maps as array-maps so it makes the decision for you. The only maps it considers really different are the sorted maps; all unsorted maps should work the same in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create empty hash-map like this:

```
(. clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap create {})
(clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap/create {})
(clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap/EMPTY)
```

You can check the source code of `hash-map`:

```
user=> (source hash-map)
(defn hash-map
  "keyval => key val
  Returns a new hash map with supplied mappings.  If any keys are
  equal, they are handled as if by repeated uses of assoc."
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
  ([] {})
  ([& keyvals]
   (. clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap (create keyvals))))
```

As you can see in the code, if you don't provide arguments, `hash-map` function returns `{}`, which is the instance of `PersistentArrayMap`.

If you really need the instance of empty `PersistentHashMap`, you can create it with the following code:

```
(. clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap create {})
```

You can check the class of created instance:

```
user=> (class (. clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap create {}))
clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap
user=> (class (clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap/create {}))
clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap
user=> (class (clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap/EMPTY)) ;; om-nom-nom's : much simpler
clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap
```

But, I'm not sure that doing this is good or necessary. Perhaps you code shouldn't depend on specific implementation class.

Comment: How do you tell `{}` is an instance of `PersistentArrayMap`?

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran You can check the above code in REPL. `(. clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap create {})` means... create PersistentHashMap using `{}`.

Comment: It seems to me that hashmap has an efficiency than arraymap when access operations is a lot.

Answer (score 7):

Another possibility is to use pre-defined EMPTY field:

```
user=> (clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap/EMPTY)
{}
```

In my opinion it is better shows your intent.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't really need to worry about this. The runtime makes a judgement on the best implementation to use. `PersistentArrayMap` is preferred (ie. it's more efficient in time and space) for a small number of key/value pairs, but promotion to `PersistentHashMap` happens once the kv limit of 8 is crossed, see [the relevant code for details](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.5.1/src/jvm/clojure/lang/PersistentArrayMap.java#L405)

```lisp
*clojure-version*
{:major 1, :minor 5, :incremental 1, :qualifier nil}

; map declared with {} with 8 kv pairs is ArrayMap
(type {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d 4 :e 5 :f 6 :g 7 :h 8})
  => clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap

; map declared with {} with 9 kv pairs is HashMap
(type {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d 4 :e 5 :f 6 :g 7 :h 8 :i 9})
  => clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap

; assoc'ing 1 kv pairs into an ArrayMap is an ArrayMap (oddly)
(type (-> {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d 4 :e 5 :f 6 :g 7 :h 8} 
          (assoc :i 9)))
clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap

; assoc'ing 2 kv pairs into an ArrayMap is an HashMap
(type (-> {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d 4 :e 5 :f 6 :g 7 :h 8} 
          (assoc :i 9) 
          (assoc :j 10)))
clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap
```